# Dummy function caused "error TS1109: Expression expected."

Tags: typescript

I want to create a dummy function to pass into a constructor inside a storybook.

Here is the definition of my dummy function

```
 const userActionHandler = (args: {
    isAllowed?: boolean,
    shouldAddNewItem?: boolean,
  }) => void;
```

However `tsc` complaints about this:

```
error TS1109: Expression expected.

149   }) => void;
                ~


Found 1 error.
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
 const userActionHandler = (args: {
    isAllowed?: boolean,
    shouldAddNewItem?: boolean,
  }) => {};
```